# PyMySQL different updates in one query?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

So I have a python script that goes through roughly 350,000 data objects, and depending on some tests, it needs to update a row which represents each one of those objects in a MySQl db. I'm also using pymysql as I've had the least trouble with it especially when sending over large select queries (select statements with `where column IN (....)` clause that can contain 100,000+ values).

Since each update for each row can be different, each update statement is different. For example, for one row we might want to update `first_name` but for another row we want to leave `first_name` untouched and we want to update `last_name`.

This is why I don't want to use the `cursor.executemany()` method which takes in one generic update statement and you then feed it the values however as I mentioned, each update is different so having one generic update statement doesn't really work for my case. I also don't want to send over 350,000 update statements individually over the wire. Is there anyway I can package all of my update statements together and send them at once?

I tried having them all in one query and using the `cursor.execute()` method but it doesn't seem to update all the rows.

Comment: How many different kinds updates are there? i.e. how many different tables are you updating with those third of a million values? and how many different columns on those tables? i.e. Is it just a few different update statements?

Comment: Are there other useful options other than 'one query' or 'one third of  million' queries? What about if the data was loaded into a `work table` in the database and manipulate it from that? Database like playing with data in tables?

Comment: @RyanVincent they all just update the same table however the table has 12 columns and each update statement can update any different combination of columns at once, from 1 column to 10 columns.

Comment: Could you write the update statement to update any column with either the new value or the existing value? Would that give you an approach to processing the new values?

Comment: It depends on the tests and how complicated they are. You may be able to write 1 big statement or 10, 1 for each column.. or more by splitting each test. Could you share the tests? It is also strange to update 350,000 rows in such a row dependent manner in a table regularly! Perhaps there is a different DB structure that could be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL #1: `CREATE TABLE t` with whatever columns you might need to change.  Make all of them `NULL` (as opposed to `NOT NULL`).

SQL #2:  Do a bulk `INSERT` (or `LOAD DATA`) of all the changes needed.  Eg, if changing only `first_name`, fill in `id` and `first_name`, but have the other columns `NULL`.

SQL #3-14:

```
UPDATE real_table
  JOIN t  ON t.id = real_table.id
  SET real_table.first_name = t.first_name
  WHERE t.first_name IS NOT NULL;
# ditto for each other column.
```

All SQLs except #1 will be time-consuming.  And, since `UPDATE` needs to build a undo log, it could timeout or otherwise be problematical.  See [a discussion of chunking](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) if necessary.

If necessary, use functions such as `COALESCE()`, `GREATEST()`, `IFNULL()`, etc.

Mass `UPDATEs` usually imply poor schema design.

(If Ryan jumps in with an 'Answer' instead of just a 'Comment', he should probably get the 'bounty'.)

Comment: Hi Rick,

I know you answered my other question about the mysql connector but I am getting a similar error when I try to Load Data Local Infile using the pymysql library. 

I get a  Broken Pipe error regardless whether I run the code from my machine or an EC2 machine where the DB is an RDS DB so I doubt the network has been that crappy for a week straight

`e_bytes
    raise err.OperationalError(2006, "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")`

Answer (score 5):

Your best performance will be if you can encode your "tests" into the SQL logic itself, so you can boil everything down to a handful of UPDATE statements.  Or at least get as many as possible done that way, so that fewer rows need to be updated individually.

For example:

```
UPDATE tablename set firstname = [some logic]
WHERE [logic that identifies which rows need the firstname updated];
```

You don't describe much about your tests, so it's hard to be sure.  But you can typically get quite a lot of logic into your WHERE clause with a little bit of work.

Another option would be to put your logic into a stored procedure.  You'll still be doing 350,000 updates, but at least they aren't all "going over the wire".  I would use this only as a last resort, though; business logic should be kept in the application layer whenever possible, and stored procedures make your application less portable.