# MySQL connector python 35 Resource temporarily unavailable with large queries?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to use MySQL connector as an alternative to pymysql as it supports multiple statements in one query for some updates I have to make ([Here is my other question related to that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139294/pymysql-different-updates-in-one-query)) however it fails for my other use case of sending over very large select statements.

I have a dynamically generated Select statement which retrieves all rows that match any of the specified values passed in; for example `Select * from table where col_a in (val_1, val_2.... val_350,000)`

I keep getting the same error for my select statements:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 212, in send_compressed
    self.sock.sendall(zip_packet)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 921, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/maldeiri/raw_data_processing/sql_retriever.py", line 22, in run
    self.mysql_cursor.execute(self.sql_statement)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 261, in _send_cmd
    packet_number)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 215, in send_compressed
    errno=2055, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'database_end_point:3306', system error: 35 Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This happens regardless if I have compress=True or False. I also don't think this is a server side issue as I mentioned the exact same Select statements seem to be working with pymysql running of the same code and machine.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: Where are you getting the 350k values in the parameters from to begin with? The database?

Comment: No, I have a raw text file that I get which has them (they are always different) and I need to pull the respective rows from the DB to do some transformations and updates using other raw data.

Comment: @RyanVincent I could and it is a work around I have but it adds more code that really shouldn't be there in my opinion. What bothers me is that I know the DB can handle it and I know python can handle it because it works using PyMYSQL so it's just frustrating to not know why it doesn't work with connector library 

1) Splitting the values in groups of 40,000
2) Constructing N number of queries and making the calls
3) Merging the results together

Comment: If I had a nickel for every time a 3rd party package got in the way of achieving a goal...

Answer (score 3):

Don't build that horrendous `IN(...)`, instead throw the values into a table, one per row.

Then do a `JOIN` to the real table to get the rows you need.  (Be sure that `col_a` is indexed in the real table; don't bother indexing it in the extra table.)

If the huge list can have dups, you should probably de-dup the list first.  See if Python can do it easily enough.  If not, you could have that one-column be the `PRIMARY KEY` and do `INSERT IGNORE` as you insert them.  Or,

```
CREATE TABLE t (val) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT or LOAD DATA ... (no dedupping)
SELECT rt.* FROM real_table
    JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT val FROM t )  ON rt.val = t.val;
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, I will consider this new desgin and implement it. 

However this brings up a new problem. Anytime I try to do a `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` I get a Broken Pipe error 

`File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 986, in _write_bytes
    self.socket.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
    raise err.OperationalError(2006, "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")`

Comment: Check `wait_timeout`, `interactive_timeout`, disk full, network problem, `tmpdir` on small filesystem.

Comment: Now I'm getting `mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'c200-aurora.cluster-cdiuhkskfb4l.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306', system error: 35 Resource temporarily unavailable` again when trying to Load Data LOCAL INFILE and it only happens sometimes. I tried the same Load statement from mysql workbench and never got the error... just when I call it from Python.

Comment: I also don't see `wait_timeout`, `interactive_timeout` as optional arguments for the connector class.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%';

Comment: Infrequent errors (assuming you are doing essentially the same thing) can be caused by a network hiccup.  If it always happens at the same time (since start of statement), that could be a good clue.

Comment: You can count it as a frequent error now. It is happening every time for that one table. Executing Load statements on another table work fine... I hate databases so much.

Comment: It fails on a huge table?  After how long?

Comment: After like 8 seconds. The table is huge but the file being loaded is only 50MB. 

The other Load statements I have tried though are also on very big tables and the file sizes are similar, but they work fine. 

Also I tried making the same statement from the workbench but it's working fine... it's just when I make it from Python. It's so wired

Comment: To add insult to injury, rebooting the DB server fixes the problem (I have an RDS instance on AWS) for one time only then it keeps happening.

Comment: Very strange.  If you have access to mysqld.err, does it give any clues?

Comment: Can't see anything in the logs so makes me feel this is a python issue.... in some strange way.